# How to filter multiple values

Tags: excel

In the image down below I have an example.
There are 2 columns with name Clientnumber. What I need is that the values under Clientnumber1 are filtered from Clientnumber and are Printed in a third sheet. In this example the filtered values are printed under the column Filtered. So the sales are included. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is advanced filter. Activate the third sheet - the one where you want the filtered data. Then select advanced filter (Data - Advanced [next to filter]) Select: Copy to another location. Select the table you want to filter as list range. Select the values you want to get as a criteria range (note that you'll have to change the title of the criteria column to match the title of the column in the table - from Clientnumber1 to Clientnumber in your case. Finally for copy to you select a cell in the third sheet.